# String variable to a DefaultMutableTreeNode object?

Tags: java, swing, casting, jtree, tree-nodes

Is it possible to convert a String variable to a DefaultMutableTreeNode object?
Please explain.
Context:

```
String s = new String(outputTagName);
Object s2 = (Object) s;
DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode2 =(DefaultMutableTreeNode) s2;
DefaultMutableTreeNode parent2 =(DefaultMutableTreeNode) parent;
model.insertNodeInto(selectedNode2, parent2, parent2.getChildCount());
```

This is the code, I wrote. This is used within an enumeration that traverses the tree in the BreadthFirstSearch fashion.
 And the 2nf line gives me this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode at ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast String object to any type other than String or Object, or one of interfaces String implements (Serializable, CharSequence, Comparable). To cast object to some type, the object **must be** of this type. String object is of type String and not of type DefaultMutableTreeNode. You cannot even make DefaultMutableTreeNode a subclass of String (in which case casting would be possible) as String class is final.

Comment: Can I convert a String to Object type and then convert Object to DefaultMutableTreeNode type?

Comment: A String is always a Object, but an Object is not always a DefaultMutableTreeNode

Comment: @Nettogrof What do you think about the ANSWER below this comment?

Answer (score 1):

That depends **entirely** on the semantics of the tree you wish to use the node with.

For example, you can create a node containing the string as simply as:

```
String s = ...; // your string
new DefaultMutableTreeNode(s);
```

Whether that will be any use to you depends on how you're using the tree.

Basically, *more context please*.  Otherwise this simple "yes" answer is the best you're going to get. :-p

Comment: What would be the semantics , that you speak of  here?
Can I have more than a yes,pretty please? :P

Comment: @fixxxer: What I mean is that the process of "conversion" your question refers to, depends on what properties you want the resulting node to have - which depends in turn on how you use it.  So my answer will create a node that wraps the given String, but if the other nodes contained `Booleans` or `Files` or `MyCustomRunnableImpl` (looked up by string ID) this wouldn't do you any good.  Basically, what I wrote will work in many situations that your question could describe, and fail in many more that it could describe.

Comment: In my experience, I hv been unable to typecaste the String object to DefaultMutableTreeMode, as the program throws errors(I was running it in Elcipse IDE).So I used setUserObject method to attach the string to the node.But this is just a temporary work-around,in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like you want to change the selected node's displaying text to some new given text. If this is the case I think this might help.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node=(DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
node.setUserObject("New Node Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Link that you have provide in your other question](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SwingTree.htm)

You can see that you can do new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Any String");

To correct your code example , the way to do it is:

```
String s = new String(outputTagName);

DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(s2);
```